# insert sdk in ios project objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk

I am working on IOS project in which i have to insert sdk of

> http://zoom.us

```
 ios app.
```

Can anyone suggest me better way to do the same

sdk link https://zoom.us/developer

I am using xcode 7

TIA

Comment: everything is explained , https://zoom.us/developer/ios/sample-app. what else needed

Comment: how to add this in my app

Comment: m getting error linker command failed with error code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Download sdk from below link

https://app.box.com/s/ok1idj50vze0e39ouz4rjray0ggjjb31

Then in Targets > Build Phases > Add new framework > Add other > Add the .framework file

or else

just drag drop the framework to your project.